# Uniqueness of system solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Assume the IVP
$$
x'''+\frac{1}{1+t^2}x''+\sin t \,x'+\frac{t}{x^2+y^2+1}=0
$$
$$
y''+e^{-t}y'+\cos (x+y)=0
$$
$$
x(0)=1,\, x'(0)=0, \, x''(0)=5, \, y(0)=0, \, y'(0)=5
$$

I want to prove that there exists a **unique solution**, the domain of which includes a neighborhood of $t=0$.

If we set
$$x_1=x,\,y_1=y$$
$$x_2=x',\, y_2=y'$$
$$x_3=x''$$
 we have
$$x_1'=x_2$$
$$x_2'=x_3$$
$$x_3'=-\frac{1}{1+t^2}x_3+\sin t\, x_2+\frac{t}{x_1^2+y_1^2+1}$$
and
$$y_1'=y_2$$
$$y_2'=-e^{-t}y_2-\cos (x_1+y_1)$$
equivalent to
$$\vec{x}'=\vec{F}(t,x,y)$$
$$\vec{y}'=\vec{G}(t,x,y)$$
Is there some way to merge these two systems and use Picard's theorem to complete the proof?

Comment: Just define the state vector as 5 dimensional, then there is only one function to consider. The ODE do not have singularities, are continuously differentiable everywhere, which gives you local unique solutions. For more global solutions you might want to compute Lipschitz constants, I see no problems to get global Lipschitz constants on $[a,\infty)\times \Bbb R^5$ for any $a<0$.

Comment: Is the fact that this function is differentiable with respect to the dependent variable (i.e $z$) equivalent to a local Lipschitz condition?

Comment: Yes, by the generalized mean value property, $$H(z_2)-H(z_1)=\int_0^1H'(z_1+s(z_2-z_1))(z_2-z_1)ds\\~\\\implies \|H(z_2)-H(z_1)\|\le\max_{s\in[0,1]}\|H'(z_1+s(z_2-z_1))\|\,\|z_2-z_1\|.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to build two distinct equations. Just set:
$$
\begin{align*}
&x_1=x  \\
&x_2=x' \\
&x_3=x'' \\
&x_4=y\\
&x_5=y'\\
\end{align*}
$$
The system tranforms to:
$$
\begin{align*}
&x_1'=x_2 \\
&x_2'=x_3 \\
&x_3'=-\frac{1}{1+t^2}x_3+\sin t\, x_2+\frac{t}{x_1^2+x_4^2+1} \\
&x_4'=x_5 \\
&x_5'=-e^{-t}x_5-\cos (x_1+x_4) \\
\end{align*}
$$
Or, written more compactly:
$$
\vec{x}'=\vec{F}(t,\vec{x})
$$
Then, there exists an arbitrary neighborhood $(-\delta,\delta)$ of the origin where $F$ is bounded.

This implies that the original system has a unique solution for $t \in (-\delta,\delta)$.